# Download big file over bad connection

Tags: curl, http, download

Is there an existing tool, which can be used to download big files over a bad connection?

I have to regularly download a relatively small file: 300 MB, but the slow (80-120 KBytes/sec) TCP connection randomly breaks after 10-120 seconds. (It's a big company's network. We contacted their admins (working from India) multiple times, but they can't or don't want to do anything.)
The problem might be with their reverse proxies / load balancers.

Up until now I used a modified version of pcurl: https://github.com/brunoborges/pcurl

I changed this line:

```sh
curl -s --range ${START_SEG}-${END_SEG} -o ${FILENAME}.part${i} ${URL} &
```

to this:

```sh
curl -s --retry 9999 --retry-delay 3 --speed-limit 2048 --speed-time 10 \
    --retry-max-time 0 -C - --range ${START_SEG}-${END_SEG} -o ${FILENAME}.part${i} ${URL} &
```

I had to add `--speed-limit 2048 --speed-time 10` because the connection mostly just hangs for minutes when it fails.

But recently even this script can't complete.

One problem is that it seems to ignore the `-C -` part, so it doesn't "continue" the segment after a retry. It seems to truncate the relating temp file, and start from the beginning after each fail. (I think the `--range` and the `-C` options cannot be used together.)

The other problem is that this script downloads all segments at the same time. It cannot have 300 segments, of which only are 10 being downloaded at a time.

I was thinking of writing a download tool in C# for this specific purpose, but if there's an existing tool, or if the curl command could work properly with different parameters, then I could spare some time.

UPDATE 1: Additional info: The parallel download functionality should not be removed, because they have a bandwidth limit (80-120 Kbytes / sec, mostly 80) per connection, so 10 connections can cause a 10 times speedup. I have to finish the file download in 1 hour, because the file is generated hourly.

Comment: Is the only option to access the files over FTP/HTTP? You can't use something like `rsync` (which will let you restart transfers)? `lftp` also allows for automatically restarting transmissions.

Comment: Yes, they restricted all access to HTTPS to their servers some years ago. BTW the server allows restart at specific position, pcurl makes use of that.

Comment: @roaima Yup, their bandwidth is more like 40-300 kbyte/sec. Changing throughout the day. I wrote the worst case. But this solution can work with the lowest as well.

Comment: You are looking for a commandline tool for scripting? Because otherwise I'd simply use FileZilla or a similar ftp/sftp client that supports restarting a download.

Comment: _"a relatively small file: 300 MB"_ Ah, way to make me feel old :)

Comment: Also, wow, that's .. an appalling network.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't edit the answer into the question.  You should either post your own answer to describe what you did, or just accept one of the existing answers and leave a comment on it if you want to add some detail about how well it worked.  The command in Stephane's answer appears to now match exactly what's in your question.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, now it's a bit redundant. I'll remove the answer from the question.

Comment: 300MB in one hour is 85 kB per second. If you get 80-120 kB/s in the average case, this should be OK without running 10 downloads in parallel? I do wonder whether that throttling is really intentional, though. If it varies so much (40-300 kB/s) it's most likely rather the network being congested on their end, so more connections make no difference anyway.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp)) is good for that. It supports a number of protocols, can download files using several concurrent parallel connections (useful where there's a lot of packet loss not caused by congestion), and can automatically resume downloads. It's also scriptable.

Here including the fine-tuning you  came up with (credits to you):

```sh
lftp -c 'set net:idle 10
         set net:max-retries 0
         set net:reconnect-interval-base 3
         set net:reconnect-interval-max 3
         pget -n 10 -c "https://host/file.tar.gz"'
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to use parallel connections: `lftp -e 'set net:timeout 15; set net:max-retries 0; set net:reconnect-interval-base 3; set net:reconnect-interval-max 3; pget -n 10 -c "https://host/file.tar.gz"; exit'`

Comment: Oh, when I removed the "net:timeout" setting, it became parallel. But it slows down after a while. I think because the connections start to "hang".

Comment: It works perfectly with the `net:idle` setting. Thank you! I'll add my solution to the question.

Comment: Note that lftp supports torrent as the underlying transfer protocol. Use it. All the other protocols it supports don't support per-chunk error detection/correction and rely on TCP to provide error detection. Note that torrent uses TCP error detection but on top of it verifies the sha1 hash of your entire file and also each block transferred over the network. In my experience a 4GB movie torrented over a 4G network typically have around two hash verification errors - this means TCP considered the received packet to be error free even though they were corrupted

Comment: If you care about your data not being corrupted, use torrent

Comment: Note that this is not compatible with Windows beyond Cygwin http://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/431

Comment: @StevenPenny, this is unix.se. Microsoft Windows is off topic here (and in my limited experience, MS Windows is useless without Cygwin anyway).

Comment: @slebetman, here the OP uses HTTPS. TLS provides extra integrity check (over TCP's weak checksum) via HMAC. Also HTTP has support for checksuming content or chunks with the `Content-MD5` and `Digest` headers (though I don't  know if `lftp` supports those or if they would be used in the OP's case). In any case, it doesn't look like torrent would be an option for the OP.

Answer (score 13):

I can't test this for you in your situation, but you should not be using `--range` with `-C -`. Here's what the man page has to say on the subject:

> Use  `-C  -` to tell `curl` to automatically find out where/how to resume the transfer. It then uses the given  output/input  files to figure that out.

Try this instead:

```sh
curl -s --retry 9999 --retry-delay 3 --speed-limit 2048 --speed-time 10 \
    --retry-max-time 0 -C - -o "${FILENAME}.part${i}" "${URL}" &
```

I'd also strongly recommend that you always double-quote your variables so that the shell won't try to parse them. (Consider a URL `https://example.net/param1=one&param2=two`, where the shell would split the value at `&`.)

Incidentally, 120 KB/s is approximately 1.2 Mb/s, which is a typical xDSL upload speed in many parts of the world. 10 seconds per MB, so a little under one hour for the entire file. Not so slow, although I do appreciate you're more concerned with reliability rather than speed.

Comment: Thank you. This approach would work, but it's slow, because it's not downloading in parallel. They have a speed limit per connection, and I have to finish the download in 1 hour, because they hourly generate the file. Updating the question.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you have more luck with `wget --continue`:

```
wget --continue ${URL}
```

See also https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wget-resume-broken-download.html

Answer (score 4):

Outside the box:  Put on an eyepatch and use bittorrent.  Make the blocksize small when you create the torrent.  Obviously, encrypt the file so anyone else who finds the torrent gets nothing useful.

Comment: It's the rare corporation that internally distributes files over torrent.

Comment: Exactly. Even if the connection is really bad and the file somehow got damaged, it should work fine. PRO-TIP: Encrypt it, rename it to 'KimKardashianNude.mp4' and let thousands of people help you with the connection. Automatic, distributed backup for free! :)

Comment: As Linus himself said - "Only wimps use tape backup: real men just upload their important stuff on ftp, and let the rest of the world mirror it ;)"

Comment: @RonJohn I know it's not commonly used but that doesn't mean it couldn't be used.  The bittorrent protocol is very good at putting up with bad connections.

Comment: @LorenPechtel a Work Order for RISK to approved the ports, a WO for the NOC to open the ports, and WOs for the Linux and Windows teams to install the torrent clients, and another WO to monitor them all so that only approved files are being transferred.  And none of that takes into account HIPPA, PCI or the fact that a file that's supposed to go from Point A to Point B is now going from Point A to Points C, D, E, F, G, H, I and J before getting to Point B.  RISK will disapprove for that very reason.

Comment: @RonJohn Yeah, there are a lot of headaches.  You can keep it from going elsewhere, though--both stations are set only to connect with the IP of the other computer.

Comment: More than once, I've had to copy prod files to my laptop from A, and then to B.  Good thing it's an official corporate laptop...  :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in my previous job (except with 300GB+ offsite database backups on an (from the office) unstable connection). Users had grave problems downloading file bigger than approx. 1 GB before the connection conked out. Since they used the standard Windows copy/paste file over an RDP connection, no wonder.

One thing I found out, was that our VPN settings were completely mismatched with the network setup (mainly the MTU length). The second thing is that Windows' file copier is NOT made for copying stuff over the internet.

My first solution was a simple FTP server, however, it didn't solve the problem of transmission time (often 3-4 hours on our connection).

My second solution was to use [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) to send the files directly to an inhouse NAS. Each night after backups were complete, Syncthing sent everything we needed back to a NAS in the office. Not only was the problem of 3+ hours transmission time solved, but I was spared the 1-2 hours to courier the data if there was a crisis. At 8AM every morning, the files would be updated on the NAS, and we had our backups ready.
Even with huge files (at one point an almost 700GB database), I have yet to experience any file corruption or other problems...

Syncthing is very easy to set up and manage and is avalable for all platforms (even phones), and has very good handling of bad connections.. if the connection fails, Syncthing simply waits a few minutes and tries again.

You do need a local folder to sync things to, but your files will be available almost as soon as they are updated.

Another good thing about syncthing, is that it can be set to *only syncronize the changes* in the file (like in a differential backup)... possibly solving a part of your bandwidth problem.

Comment: +1 for mentioning syncthing - a google drive/dropbox alternative for backups

Answer (score 1):

You might consider an old-school solution for moving files over a lousy connection - [zmodem](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/run/apph_01.htm).

This was developed back when 2400 baud modems with people picking up the phones and bombing out the connection was the norm.  Could be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Kermit](http://www.kermitproject.org/kermit.html):

> The feature that distinguishes Kermit protocol from most others is its wide range of settings to allow adaptation to any kind and quality of connection between any two kinds of computer — packet length, packet encoding, window size, character set, error-detection method, timeouts, pauses. Most other protocols are designed to work only on certain kinds or qualities of connections, and/or between certain kinds of computers or like file systems, and therefore work poorly (or not at all) elsewhere and offer few if any methods to adapt to unplanned-for situations. Kermit, on the other hand, allows you to achieve successful file transfer and the highest possible performance on any given connection."